# Load images from url to recyclerview without 3rd party libraries

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview

A potential employer asked me to make a simple app that would load from JSON data to a recyclerview.

**The catch is:** I cannot use any 3rd party libraries to load images.

Does anyone know of a current tutorial I can use. I searched online and there seem to be different methods, and unfortunately up to now, I’ve relied heavily on `Picasso` and `Glide`.

My code is basically setup to get the JSON data from a AsyncTask Loader and setup the recyclerview and adapter in the loader's `onLoadFinish()`.

Ideally I would like to get the url image from within my adaptor's  `onBindViewHolder`, by calling an AsyncTask.  Is that feasible? Or should I do it differently.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I haven't tried it but it is possible. Please refer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37134590/8003636

Comment: the json contain url of the image, or image base 64?

Comment: you have solved getting URL's from JSON, you just want to load images right?

Comment: I have posted an answer, check it out if it solves your problem

Comment: The image url is in my arraylist of custom objects that is going into the adapter.

Comment: Thank you I will try out this.  I will post back. Appreciate all the help.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20120712203915/http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-loading-image-from-url-http/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I found a solution, you can check out this link for more detailed description
[Android Hive - Load images from URL-HTTP](https://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-loading-image-from-url-http/)

Manifest Permission:

```
    <!-- Internet Permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <!-- Permission to write to external storage -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

MainActivity Code:

```
        // Loader image - will be shown before loading image
        int loader = R.drawable.loader;

        // Imageview to show
        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

        // Image url
        String image_url = "https://api.androidhive.info/images/sample.jpg";

        // ImageLoader class instance
        ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());

        // whenever you want to load an image from url
        // call DisplayImage function
        // url - image url to load
        // loader - loader image, will be displayed before getting image
        // image - ImageView 
        imgLoader.DisplayImage(image_url, loader, image);
```

ImageLoader Class:

```
public class ImageLoader {

    MemoryCache memoryCache=new MemoryCache();
    FileCache fileCache;
    private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews=Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
    ExecutorService executorService; 

    public ImageLoader(Context context){
        fileCache=new FileCache(context);
        executorService=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    }

    int stub_id = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    public void DisplayImage(String url, int loader, ImageView imageView)
    {
        stub_id = loader;
        imageViews.put(imageView, url);
        Bitmap bitmap=memoryCache.get(url);
        if(bitmap!=null)
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else
        {
            queuePhoto(url, imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(loader);
        }
    }

    private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView)
    {
        PhotoToLoad p=new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
        executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmap(String url)
    {
        File f=fileCache.getFile(url);

        //from SD cache
        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        if(b!=null)
            return b;

        //from web
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap=null;
            URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Exception ex){
           ex.printStackTrace();
           return null;
        }
    }

    //decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
        try {
            //decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

            //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;
            int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
            int scale=1;
            while(true){
                if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp/=2;
                height_tmp/=2;
                scale*=2;
            }

            //decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize=scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
        return null;
    }

    //Task for the queue
    private class PhotoToLoad
    {
        public String url;
        public ImageView imageView;
        public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i){
            url=u;
            imageView=i;
        }
    }

    class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
        PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
            this.photoToLoad=photoToLoad;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            Bitmap bmp=getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
            memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
            if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
            Activity a=(Activity)photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
            a.runOnUiThread(bd);
        }
    }

    boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
        String tag=imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
        if(tag==null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    //Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable
    {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p){bitmap=b;photoToLoad=p;}
        public void run()
        {
            if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            if(bitmap!=null)
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            else
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        memoryCache.clear();
        fileCache.clear();
    }

}
```

File Cache Class:

```
public class FileCache {

    private File cacheDir;

    public FileCache(Context context){
        //Find the dir to save cached images
        if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
            cacheDir=new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"TempImages");
        else
            cacheDir=context.getCacheDir();
        if(!cacheDir.exists())
            cacheDir.mkdirs();
    }

    public File getFile(String url){
        String filename=String.valueOf(url.hashCode());
        File f = new File(cacheDir, filename);
        return f;

    }

    public void clear(){
        File[] files=cacheDir.listFiles();
        if(files==null)
            return;
        for(File f:files)
            f.delete();
    }

}
```

Memory Class :

```
public class MemoryCache {
    private Map<String, SoftReference<Bitmap>> cache=Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<String, SoftReference<Bitmap>>());

    public Bitmap get(String id){
        if(!cache.containsKey(id))
            return null;
        SoftReference<Bitmap> ref=cache.get(id);
        return ref.get();
    }

    public void put(String id, Bitmap bitmap){
        cache.put(id, new SoftReference<Bitmap>(bitmap));
    }

    public void clear() {
        cache.clear();
    }
}
```

Utils Class:

```
public class Utils {
    public static void CopyStream(InputStream is, OutputStream os)
    {
        final int buffer_size=1024;
        try
        {
            byte[] bytes=new byte[buffer_size];
            for(;;)
            {
              int count=is.read(bytes, 0, buffer_size);
              if(count==-1)
                  break;
              os.write(bytes, 0, count);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex){}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Then I'd suggest you to download the image in AsyncTask using `HttpURLConnection` and save it to the device temporarily and then load it in the imageview. Doing the entire process in `onBindViewHolder` isn't a bad idea but downloading each image and saving it to device then again loading to the app can be costly. So try caching them to memory.